# First value of similar records

Tags: sql, min

I have the following query where for `product_id` there could be more than one `USC_Code` and `USC_description`. I want to just display the `product_id` once and the first `usc_code` and `usc_description` that it comes across.

I've tried `first_value` but that didn't give me what I was looking for and `Min` works but there's no guarantee I would get the correct `USC_Code` that goes along with the `USC_Description`.

Any other suggestions or code to try?

Thanks

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, MANUFACTURER_NAME,
       USC_CODE, USC_DESCRIPTION,
       BRAND_GENERIC_DESCRIPTION
FROM ADMIN.PRODUCT_DIM
Where USC_CODE is not null
And PRODUCT_ID <> 123
Group by PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, MANUFACTURER_NAME,
         USC_CODE, USC_DESCRIPTION, BRAND_GENERIC_DESCRIPTION
ORDER By PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: Tag you question with the database you are using.

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using? MSSQL, MySQL or Oracle? and is there an unique key for records?

Comment: I'm using WinSQL if that helps or matters. Thanks

Comment: what data type is USC_Code?

Comment: Didn't notice a unique key as the table can have similar rows but product_id combined with pack_id would make the record unique.

Comment: Also how would you determine the first usc_code? Is there a timestamp or any other column which could do that?

Comment: No timestamp or anything like that. It's fine to just take the first one in the table but need to have the correct usc_description go along with it. Sort of how Access uses FIRST. I believe in Access it would give me the first value of USC and Desc and it should be the correct corresponding USC to Desc.

Comment: You could use a subselect to get the correct usc_description.

Comment: I m not sure about access but most rdms dost understand the concept of first. So if you enter 3 records and select them again, there is no guarantee that you will get them in same order as they were entered.

Comment: And what is the reason for this totally unnecessary group by clause?

Comment: Btw one could write a query that gets just a random record matching your product_id. But what is the use of it? You say hey here is my product_id and give me a just some value for USC_code. It makes no sense.

Comment: There is no reliable definition of "first". The database engine is free to store and retrieve your records in any order it wants, including using different methods on successive requests. You need to use a window function (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY <something>) and then request first from each window (where row_number = 1)